# Why do the speeds of two ceiling fans vary on all speed settings?

Tags: electrical

I have two ceiling fans on one branch of a 20 amp circuit. One fan runs faster than the other on all three speeds. Could this more likely be due to a loose neutral or connection or a malfunction of the fan?

Comment: Are they identical fans, same distance from the ceiling?

Comment: A loose neutral would cause all kinds of problems - but consistently varying speed would **not** be one of them.

Comment: Maybe they were wired in series. I'd expect uniform voltage drop, but who knows?

Answer (score 1):

Motors don’t always spin at the same speed even if the same brand, model and horse power.  They may have different speeds. I support a 1200 horse wood chipper with 3ea 400 horse motors. To get this monster to run and have the system balanced the motors need to be running at the same speed. we had to add variable frequency drives and match the full load speeds and current draws, so in short It could be the motor or the speed controller is not calibrated the same on both motors but fans usually have multiple windings for speed control and they can and usually are slightly different I see +- 50 rpm difference on motors rated at or around 1750 RPM. The one exception would be synchronous motors these are usually dead on and tied to line frequency.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know for sure without disassembling the fan, but there's a good chance that the motor inside is a 2-phase motor. But the fan is wired to a single-phase electric supply, so how can this be?

The capacitor. One winding of the motor is connected directly to the line and neutral, while the other winding is wired to line and neutral with the capacitor in series. The capacitor (ideally) causes a 90 degree phase shift in the voltage and this "creates" the second phase.

Capacitors are notoriously inaccurate. They're labeled with some nominal value, but the actual capacitance will differ. There are many grades of capacitors. In electronics power supplies a tolerance as much as -20%/+80% is common -- in other words, they might be anywhere from 3/4 of the marked value to nearly double the marked value, and this is normal and acceptable. Apparently motor run capacitors for HVAC applications often allow tolerance of just +/-6%. I don't know what tolerance to expect inside a ceiling fan.. Capacitance also varies with age, temperature, the applied voltage, etc.

Tying it all together, the inaccurate capacitance causes changes in the voltage feeding the second winding of the motor. Its phase relation to the voltage on the primary winding won't be exactly 90 degrees, and this will result in reduced torque and/or speed from the motor. The two fans may run at different speeds because their capacitors always were a little different and/or have degraded differently over time.